# Who was the first to use $\bigwedge$ and $\bigvee$ as universal and existential quantifiers?

Tags: notation, math-history, quantifiers

It's not surprised that somebody uses $\bigwedge$ and $\bigvee$ as universal and existential quantifiers since
$$
\bigwedge_{x\in A}\,\varphi(x)\Leftrightarrow \varphi(a_0)\wedge\varphi(a_1)\wedge\varphi(a_2)\wedge\cdots\Leftrightarrow\forall x\in A\,\varphi(x)
$$
and
$$
\bigvee_{x\in A}\,\varphi(x)\Leftrightarrow \varphi(a_0)\vee\varphi(a_1)\vee\varphi(a_2)\vee\cdots\Leftrightarrow\exists x\in A\,\varphi(x).
$$

Such uses could be found in

- (@Mauro ALLEGRANZA 's discovery) P. Lorenzen. *Einführung in die operative Logik und Mathematik*. Die Grundlehren der mathematischen Wissenschaften, vol. 78. Springer-Verlag, Berlin, **1955**. p.3. Writing in German.
- (@Mauro ALLEGRANZA 's discovery) P. Lorenzen. *Formale Logik*. Sammlung Goschen, Bd. 1176/1176a. Walter de Gruyter & Co., Berlin, **1958**. 165S. Writing in German and for an English translation see *Formal Logic*. Translated by P Crosson. D. Reidel Publishing Company, 1965. p.74.
- (@Mauro ALLEGRANZA 's discovery) H. Hermes. *Aufzählbarkeit, Entscheidbarkeit, Berechenbarkeit: Einführung in die Theorie der rekursiven Funktionen*. Springer-Verlag, Berlin, **1961**. Writing in German and for an English translation see *Enumerability, Decidability, Computability: An Introduction to the Theory of Recursive Functions*. Translated by G. T. Herman and O. Plassmann. Springer-Verlag, Berlin, 1965. p.67.
- (@Mauro ALLEGRANZA 's discovery) T. Skolem. Investigations on a comprehension axiom without negation in the defining propositional functions. *Notre Dame Journal of Formal Logic*, **1960**, (1-2):13-22.
- (@Mauro ALLEGRANZA 's discovery) D. Kalish and R. Montague. *Logic: Techniques of Formal Reasoning*. Harcourt, Brace & World, Inc. **1964**. p.86.
- (My discovery) G. Kreisel and J. L. Krivine. *Elements of Mathematical Logic (Model
  Theory)*. North-Holland Publishing Company, **1967**, pp.17-19.
- (My discovery) K. Kuratowski and A. Mostowski, *Set theory*, North-Holland Publishing Company, **1968**, pp.45-46.

Furthermore, such uses could be dated back to **1950**. In

- (My discovery) P. Lorenzen. Konstruktive Begründung der Mathematik. *Mathematische Zeitschrift*, **1950**, 53(2):162-202. See https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007%2FBF01162411.pdf . Received on **February 13, 1950** and writing in German.
- (My discovery) P. Lorenzen. Algebraische und Logistische Untersuchungen Über Freie Verbände. *The Journal of Symbolic Logic*, **1951**, 16(2):81-106. https://www.jstor.org/stable/pdf/2266681.pdf . Received on **March 17, 1950** and writing in German.
- (My discovery) P. Lorenzen. Die Widerspruchsfreiheit der klassischen Analysi. *Mathematische Zeitschrift*, **1951**, 54(1):1-24. https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007%2FBF01175131.pdf . Received on **July 15, 1950** and writing in German.
- (My discovery) P. Lorenzen. Ma und Integral in der konstruktiven Analysis. *Mathematische Zeitschrift*, **1951**, 54(3):275-290. https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007%2FBF01574829.pdf . Received on **April 18, 1951** and writing in German.

Lorenzen began to use $\bigwedge_x\varphi(x)$ as "$\varphi(x)$ for all $x$" and $\bigvee_x\varphi(x)$ as "$\varphi(x)$ for some $x$" simultaneously.

But I can't determine whether there are others who made such uses in an earlier time. So my question is: **Who was the first to use $\bigwedge$ and $\bigvee$ as universal and existential quantifiers respectively?**

Comment: For the history of introduction of mathematical symbols, see  this site http://jeff560.tripod.com/set.html. See as well https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Table_of_mathematical_symbols_by_introduction_date. See more generally http://www-history.mcs.st-and.ac.uk/ . I must say I am surprised that $\bigwedge$ and $\bigvee$ have been used as **quantifiers** (instead of connectives) at one time.

Comment: For an eraly occurence see Paul Lorenzen, [Formal logic (Reidel, 1965)](https://books.google.it/books?id=W7KAXAwH82EC&pg=PA73), page 74.

Comment: Also Donald Kalish & Richard Montague, Logic Techniques of Formal Reasoning (Harcourt Brace, 1967).

Comment: @Mauro ALLEGRANZA I revised the information as above and did some improvements from your notes.

Comment: I think that [Paul Lorenzen](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paul_Lorenzen#Dialogische_Logik) can be the source. See [Einführung in die operative Logik und Mathematik (1955)](https://books.google.it/books?id=-H6gBgAAQBAJ&pg=PA2), page 2.

Comment: This possible origin is supported by texts from "German" logicians ; [Th.Skolem (1960)](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.ndjfl/1093956425), G.Kreisel (see above), [H.Hermes (1960)](https://books.google.it/books?id=x2vrCAAAQBAJ&pg=PA1) in the end '50s.

Comment: @Mauro ALLEGRANZA I found that Lorenzen had made such uses in 1950.

Comment: This question belongs on [HSM SE](http://hsm.stackexchange.com), not Math SE.

Comment: I'm not sure this is what you want, but I believe I can find $\prod$  used for universal quantification long before 1950. This is relevant because the intended meaning was the same as  $\bigwedge$: the $\prod$ stands for “logical product” which is how the $\land$ operation is viewed in Boolean logic. So the author was using the symbol that meant logical-and that was current, but $\land$ hadn't been introduced yet. If this _is_ what you are looking for let me know and I will try to find a cite.

Comment: @MJD It's clear that Peirce was the first to use $\prod$ and$\sum$ as universal and existential quantifiers respectively in 1883.